# The application has stopped unexpectedly FrameLayout + ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-framelayout

I'm trying practing FrameLayout using ImageView. When i build the code there nothing wrong about it. But when i tried to run it using AVD Android 2.2 the program won't run.

It's say "The application framelayout(process.com.framelayout) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    >
<TableRow>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<ImageView
    android:src = "@drawable/pict01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<ImageView
    android:src = "@drawable/pict02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</FrameLayout>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<ImageView
    android:src = "@drawable/pict03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<ImageView
    android:src = "@drawable/pict04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</FrameLayout>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Please post full stack trace.

Comment: And show your JAVA class as well.

Comment: where i can find that? sorry i newbie in android

Comment: Your class code and your logcat.

Comment: do you mean framelayout.java for the class code? where i can find my logcat? i'm using netbeans IDE 8.0.2. Sorry for very basic question

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get error message:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try
        {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
         {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
             dialog.setTitle("error message");

            dialog.setMessage(Log.getStackTraceString(e));

            dialog.create().show();
         }
    }
```